# Find $n$ such that $x^2 + x + 1$ is a factor of $(x+1)^n - x^n - 1$.

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I have to find the form of n i.e. whether n is even or odd and whether it is multiple of 2 or 3 such that:

$x^2 + x + 1$ is a factor of $(x+1)^n - x^n - 1$

What I tried:

$$x^2 + x + 1 = (x + 1)^2 - x $$

also,

$$(x+1)^n-x^n-1= \binom{n}{o}x^n + \binom{n}{1}x^{n-1} + ... + \binom{n}{n-1}x + \binom{n}{n}.1 - x^n - 1$$

$$=\binom{n}{1}x^{n-1} + ... + \binom{n}{n-1}x$$

after getting this far I tried with taking x and n common but still couldn't able to find the right direction.

I need extra hints to solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The roots of $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$ are the cube roots of unity. Call them $w, w^2$. As  $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$, we get $w + 1 = -w^2$ and $w^2 + 1 = -w$. Thus, the problem reduces to finding $n$, such that $(-1)^{n+1}*w^{2n} + w^n + 1 = 0$. Thus the answer is, whenever n is not divisible by 3 and n is not divisible by 2, i.e., $n\equiv 1,5\mod 6$.

Comment: I think it should be $n  \equiv 1,5 \mod 6$.

Comment: Woah, thanks. The answer that I got was is n is even and it is a multiple of three. The final equation that I got is $[(-1)^n+1]*[w^2n-w^n]=0$ which gives the required solution.

Comment: @Bernard I still think, it shouldn't be $4 \mod 6$. If $n = 6k+4$, then it becomes $(1+w)^4 - w^4 -1 = w^8 - w^4 -1 = 2*w^8 $ which does not equal 0.

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry for such an error, I computed too hastily soon this morning and didn't take time to check I'll withdraw my comment. I think you should add the final form of the solutuion in terms of congruence mod 6 to you answer

Comment: @Bernard, done.